# Movable Floating Action Button

Tags: android

How to add movable floating action button in this view?

[My XML Layout design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQbBS.png)

When I try to add a `FloatingActionButton` other layouts are changing its position.

What are the other options I am having?

Comment: just be sure to be adding your floatingbutton inside your main parent layout

Answer (score 1):

You can use Relative Layout so they can be independent from each other.

```
<RelativeLayout ....>

    <FloatingActionButton
     ....
     //You can set your paramaters here
     ....
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

     <yourLayouts/>

</RelativeLayout>
```